# SUMIF with VLOOKUP based on date range in multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, spreadsheet

I have a sheet called "Orders" in which I add each order, its date and amount.

In a separate sheet, I have a monthly summary table.

I want a cell in the summary table to look at the "Orders" sheet, and if the date (in Orders, row G) falls between Jan 1 and Jan 31, I want the total from Orders, column AE to show in the summary table. I'll do this for each month.

This is what I have so far:

=SUMIF(VLOOKUP(AE4:AE5,'Orders'!G4:G5,">=1-Jan-2021″,G4:G5,”<=31-Jan-2021″),0)

Obviously that isn't right (I'm just playing around and don't really know what I'm doing!), but maybe I'm getting close.

Note that new rows (i.e., orders) will be added to the Orders sheet throughout the year, so I want AE5 and G5 in the formula to update automatically as I add a new row.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [SUMIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) would be more appropriate?

Comment: "SUMIF with VLOOKUP based on date range in multiple sheets" is the question.. but where is the 'other sheet' you refer to other than "Orders" sheet ?

Comment: The other sheet is called "Summary". It's part of the same workbook. Apologies if I'm not being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method, which requires a few more columns but isn't terrible. You could probably shorten this a little, but if you're in a pinch then it works.

In your orders sheet, add two more columns titled "Month" and "Year".

Month Formula (which extracts the numeric month from your date):

```
Cell C2: =MONTH(B2)
```

Year Formula (which extracts the numeric year from your date):

```
Cell D2: =YEAR(B2)
```

Then in your summary data, you create a SUMIFs formula. Picture below.

```
Cell K2: =SUMIFS(E:E,C:C,I2,D:D,J2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I've not misunderstood your requirement then sumifs (plural) itself can help out,

Conveniently you can have a named range "total" for the column G and "date" for column AE of the orders sheet

If you want to add dates greater than 1st of Dec and less than 5th of Dec then in the cell of the summary sheet you can add

SUMIFS(total,date,">=1/12/20",date,"<5/12/20")

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some problems visualizing what your spreadsheet looks like, but assuming the dates you are checking against are in column G and your totals are in column AE, I think the following would work:

`=SUMIFS(AE1:AE1000;G1:G1000;"<="&DATE(2020;1;31);G1:G1000;">="&DATE(2020;1;1))`

If I wanted to make this formula to autoexpand as I added more rows to the table, I'd change my data into an actual table, and refer to the ranges by their headers. Or you can just do what I've done here, and set a range that is significantly larger than what you are likely to use and hope you never add any entries outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, doesn't this just assume all data is in one sheet? I have two separate sheets, one called "Orders" and one called "Summary". Dates are on "Orders" in column G, and the data I want to sum is on "Orders" in column AE. I want to return the values onto the "Summary" sheet.

Comment: @JJ48152 You can reference cells in another sheet in the formula. Just switch to that sheet while writing in the formula, and Excel will help you get the right syntax.

Comment: Ok, so now I have: 

=SUMIFS(Orders!AE4:AE5;Orders!G4:G5;"<="&DATE(21;1;31);Orders!G4:G5;">="&DATE(21;1;1))

What I'm aiming for: If any data in the "Orders" sheet, cells AE4 to AE5, is a date between the beginning and end of January 2021, then add the figures in "Orders", cells G4 to G5, and return the answer to cell B2 the sheet called "Summary".

But it's still returning an error.
Thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found it! The formula that has worked is

=SUMIFS(Orders!$AE4:$AE5,Orders!$G4:$G5,">=1/1/21",Orders!$G4:$G5,"<=1/31/21")

Thanks for all your help!